# Database Algebra: derivate properties out of database structure

Tags: sql, database, sqlalchemy, algebra, relational-algebra

I am currently working on a piece of code that use sqlalchemy to produce SQL queries from a database structure model. The goal of this tool is to work no matter what database structure is defined.

For this to work correctly, I need to implement rules to filter useless generated queries.

For instance:

```
SELECT SUM(col_a)
FROM (
      SELECT SUM(col_b) AS col_a
      FROM tableA
      GROUP BY col_c
     )
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(col_b) FROM tableA
```

produce the exact same result. Therefore, one of these should not be generated (the more complex for instance)

Other example:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE col_a = True and col_a = False
```

This query always return an empty set

For both of these examples, the result is predictable statically (using only the database structure without the data sotred in it).

**So, I am wondering if some algebra exists that can express theses kind of concept to help me generate properties about columns, tables, queries results' etc.**

An example of properties would be:
If two columns col_a and col_b are connected through a one to one relationship, there will always be only one value of col_b for each row of SELECT col_a. Hence:

```
SELECT col_a FROM tableA WHERE col_b = "value1" and col_b = "value2"
```

will always return an empty set (also because col_b can't have two values at the same time but whatever..)

Comment: Hi. If you would google your question you would find that this topic is relational database optimization/implementation & that the relevant underlying algebra is (some version of) relational algebra & that it is addressed in a chapter of most relational database textbooks, of which dozens are free online, and that this is also a stackoverflow faq. You already tagged this with relational-algebra so why are you asking? Also, a DBMS already has such optimization as part of its functionality so why duplicate it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a large quantity of published research into query optimization generally and if you aren't familiar with that then take a look at research archives and publications like SIGMOD Record.

Your kind of semantic optimization is a hard problem to solve for SQL. You could probably make things much easier by using a language based more properly on relational algebra and then maybe translating that to SQL as a final step. SQL is not relational and is not equivalent to RA. The peculiarities of SQL mean that queries you might expect to be equivalent in fact are not.

Just some of the extra difficulties you have to deal with in SQL: un-named columns (your first two example queries); aliasing (your first query is illegal and requires an alias but the others do not); type conversion; context-sensitive rules for column name scoping; lack of keys and key derivation; duplicate columns; duplicate rows; three-value logic. These "features" and omissions make query processing more complex without being of any particular value to the query author/user.